# Why are magnets attracted to negative side in battery

Tags: electromagnetism, batteries

I have been experimenting with magnets, and built an Homopolar motor however it works but the magnet only attracts the negative side of the AA battery (the flat side of a battery) which I thought was intriguing as its my first time I found this out myself, but my question is why is the negative side only attracted to the magnet?

The battery is made of Zinc Chloride.

Comment: What kind of battery are you talking about? It should be written somewhere.

Comment: Well that is the size factor, the chemistry of the battery is more important. Look at [AA-batteries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AA_battery). It has probably one of the chemistries where the cathode(negative electrode) is made from a ferromagnetic material. It would be even magnetic if you cut the battery in half (don't do that please).